# How to get Facebook Picture and Friends using Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, azure-authentication

Is it possible to get Facebook Profile Picture and user friends using Azure Mobile services Claims or any other way?

On the azure backend as shown below,

- User picture is missing there if it is not public profile. It looks
  like public profile is only link to facebook profile
- I set user_friends but when I request identites with the code below,
  i see 9 claims (name, surname, fullname, gender, profile etc.) but I
  dont get any friends information.

[image]

Code I am using is simply

```
 identities = await App.Client.InvokeApiAsync<List<AppServiceIdentity>>("/.auth/me");
```

According to the documentation, it should return what i set in the backend as dictionary of claims type and value.

I am able to achieve this using simple http request as below

```
  var requestUrl = $"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/friends?fields=id,picture.width(72).height(72),name&access_token=" + accessToken;
```

But i want a general solution using azure backend if possible?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, your could only retrieve the basic profile (`name`, `picture`, `email`,etc.) from the current authenticated user. Per my understanding, if you hope your mobile app backend would handle the requests against the Graph API of facebook stead of retrieving the access token and send request in your mobile client, you could create a custom Web API and use the following code to get the access token and send request in your mobile backend:

```html
// Get the credentials for the logged-in user.
var credentials =
    await this.User
    .GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<FacebookCredentials>(this.Request);

if (credentials.Provider == "Facebook")
{
    // Create a query string with the Facebook access token.
    var requestUrl = $"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/friends?fields=id,picture.width(72).height(72),name&access_token=" + credentials.AccessToken;

    // Create an HttpClient request.
    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

    // Request the current user info from Facebook.
    var resp = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // Do something here with the Facebook user information.
    var fbInfo = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

For your mobile client, you could leverage `InvokeApiAsync` to call the related custom Web API provided by your mobile backend. More details, you could refer to [How to: Work with authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#how-to-work-with-authentication) and [Custom HTTP Endpoints](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter4/custom/).

Comment: Yes that works fine for facebook but claims for azure mobile services is more generic if i use twitter or google it handles for me to get User info but it looks like picture and userfriends are missing although we can set on azure portal

Comment: The scope(s) you chosen on azure portal define the permission(s) for accessing the related resources, but azure seems just pull the basic userinfo (name, picture, email,etc.).

Comment: After you logged, you could try to send a request to your backend, then you could leverage the access token to retrieve the resources you expected, then you could try to update the claims for the current user on the server side or regenerate a new authenctionToken with the extended claims via `AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken` to your client side, details you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#how-to-work-with-authentication).